# How can I determine the right Apache POI libraries for my java code and for excel file that should be imported to java,

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am working on a Java project. I should be able to import Excel files to my Java swing GUI, but it needed apache POI. The problem here is how do I determine the right POI jar files and the necessary POI to be imported in my libraries? It is so bothersome if I import all of the POI in my libraries. And my Excel files have an extension of `xlsx`, the 2018 Microsoft Excel extension. If you have any block of codes that can now import, that would be really helpful.

Comment: Do you have a maven project or a plain java project?

Comment: I think you want to say Apache POI instead of PIO. If so, this link has the samples you need: https://www.mkyong.com/java/apache-poi-reading-and-writing-excel-file-in-java/ (note that this samples use Maven)

Comment: Yes I have a main but for now, it doesnt contain any codes.

Comment: Just get the last version of maven apache-poi if you are using Maven. Else, search for the good dependency for your build system